# How to write a sequence recursively

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I write the sequence
1, 1/2,   1/2,   1/3,   1/3,   1/3,   1/4,   1/4,   1/4,   1/4,   1/5,   1/5,   1/5,   1/5,   1/5, …

in closed form or recursively?

I am trying to find a sequence that converges to 0 but the series diverges.

Comment: The sequence $u_n=1/n$ has divergent sum, see [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).

Comment: If you're trying to answer a question for a class, as long as you find a reason to explain the sequence there should be no need to write the sequence in any standard fashion (i.e. closed form or recursively).

Comment: Also, another way to generate such a sequence: take any sequence $a_n$ with $a_n \to \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/n = 0$, and define $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$. For instance, you could also have considered the sequence
$$
b_n = \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Your sequence can be written as:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\lfloor \sqrt{2n} + 0.5 \rfloor}$$

This is the inverse of [OEIS sequence A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024).